AWS RDS Blue-Green Deployment replication error: role "rdsrepladmin" cannot SET ROLE to "rds_superuser"
I am trying to use the AWS managed Blue-Green deployment feature on my Postgres RDS db. However, I keep getting an error about role "rdsrepladmin" cannot SET ROLE to "rds_superuser" when trying to switch over. I have not been able to find any reason for this error, however.
The DB I'm deploying does have replication slots in use normally, but for this deployment I have dropped all subscriptions. I've tuned the worker counts per AWS docs, but no luck.
I have tried rebooting the green and blue environments, after creating the deployment but before switching over.
UPDATE: I found 2 possible solutions. Either turn on rds.run_logical_replication_as_subscription_owner. OR, fully turn off all my cron jobs before even creating the bg deployment.
